# Yii2 Restful API - add possibility to auth with session

Tags: session, authentication, yii2

In my Restful API project I use Bearer Token Authentication.
But now there is need to use Session Authentication in only one Controller to perform special actions with files. But I don't really understand how I should change behaviors method for that. What I have done,

```
'enableSession' => true
```

My behaviors method looks like:

```
public function behaviors() {
    $behaviors =  parent::behaviors();
    unset($behaviors['authenticator']);
    $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
      'class' => HttpBearerAuth::className(),
      'except' => ['options'],
    ];
    $behaviors['access'] = [
      'class' => AccessControl::className(),
      'rules' => [
        [
          'allow' => true,
          'actions' => [
            'options',
          ],
        ],
        [
          'actions'=>['content'],
          'allow' => true,
          'roles' => ['admin'],
        ]
      ],
    ];
    return $behaviors;
}
```

I think there should be some changes in authenticator settings, use something else except HttpBearerAuth or may be something else, please help